# The whois.whois function always gets a timed out error

Tags: python, whois

The `whois.whois` function always gets a timed out error.
At first, I thought it was because my project is written in Python 2.7 but I also checked in 3.7 and got the same error.
I checked the address on the online website that uses whois and the link worked and didn't get this error.
Anyone knows why this is happening?

```
import whois

w = whois.whois("https://stackoverflow.com")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\whois\__init__.py", line 43, in whois
    text = nic_client.whois_lookup(None, domain.encode('idna'), flags)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\whois\whois.py", line 264, in whois_lookup
    result = self.whois(query_arg, nichost, flags)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\whois\whois.py", line 142, in whois
    s.connect((hostname, 43))
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Comment: It appears that you might have a network issue where in you can't contact the whois server. You might want to check your firewall settings that might be preventing your program from contacting the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has at least two problems, and you may have a network problem also.

However, there is no reason for it not to work on Python2.

## About the code

This works perfectly fine:

```
In [7]: import whois

In [8]: print whois.query('stackoverflow.com').expiration_date
2020-02-02 11:59:59
```

Note two things:

- whois is about domain names, not URLs; so you should pass a domain name; note more generally that for new endeavors you should have a look at RDAP instead of whois since you will get a far better experience
- you need to use `whois.query` not `whois.whois` (you are not saying which version of the library you use, but at its documentation page on https://pypi.org/project/whois/ you can clearly see it is `whois.query` so I do not know where your `whois.whois` comes from).

## About the network

You show a network error. It is not 100% clear but you may or may not have access to the whois servers you want to query.

Easy way to test: just use the command line `whois` from the same box as your code (but again use a domain name, not a URL as parameter) and you will see what is happening.

You can even do directly a telnet on port 43 as whois does nothing else.

```
$ echo 'stackoverflow.com' | nc whois.verisign-grs.com 43 | grep 'Expiry'
   Registry Expiry Date: 2020-02-02T11:59:59Z
```